# How to remove the speech event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition

I am working on the following code

```
SpeechRecognizer sr2 = new SpeechRecognizer();
```

...

```
sr2.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr2_SpeechRecognized);
```

...

```
void sr2_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e){}
```

In here the very first code shows the initialization of the speech recognizer, second code shows the registering to event handler and the third code shows the Event handler.

Now, I need to remove this event handler. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
  sr2.SpeechRecognized -= new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr2_SpeechRecognized);
```

Since the `Remove` method uses `Delegate.Equals` to check for equality, you don't need to actually store the `new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr2_SpeechRecognized);` anywhere, and can simply make the call above to remove the handler.